# REST: dataset aggregation returns Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: google-fit

We are getting the following error on a couple users but it is unclear why; just started recently.  Any insights into why and how to resolve or work around it?

POST to https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate?fields=bucket with:

```
{"aggregateBy":[{"dataTypeName":"com.google.step_count.delta"},{"dataTypeName":"com.google.calories.expended"},{"dataTypeName":"com.google.distance.delta"}],"endTimeMillis":1586841780000,"startTimeMillis":1585545780000,"bucketByActivitySegment":{"minDurationMillis":1000}}
```

Responds with:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Cache-Control: private
Server: ESF
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Date: Tue, 05 May 2020 04:56:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Error: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidArgument"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `?fields=bucket` will do?

Comment: Its been there since we implemented in 2015 -- the Google Fit documentation back then wasn't great and not sure where that came from (I believe it was the API Explorer).  But as indicated, it works for 99.5+% of the  users, so not sure this is it, but can try removing it.

Comment: it's not that, the request fails on the "try it now" in the rest docs. I've simply never come across it, and I suspect it is redundant.

Comment: [Repro link](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22aggregateBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22dataTypeName%22%3A%22com.google.step_count.delta%22%7D%2C%7B%22dataTypeName%22%3A%22com.google.calories.expended%22%7D%2C%7B%22dataTypeName%22%3A%22com.google.distance.delta%22%7D%5D%2C%22endTimeMillis%22%3A1586841780000%2C%22startTimeMillis%22%3A1585545780000%2C%22bucketByActivitySegment%22%3A%7B%22minDurationMillis%22%3A1000%7D%7D%7D)

Comment: If I issue this request, it fails with this error message also. It looks like it's because I don't have an activity stream to read the segments from. Could you check to see if this is the case for this small handful of accounts you see a failure with?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance on this. It appears that the error is basically a 404 and proceeding afterwards is fine.  Not sure why this is new, but it appears to be resolved.

Comment: Seeing this same behave for some users. In the past, when a new account was not linked to any device (and therefore no activity stream) this error would appear with state 400: `unknown datasource: derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:merge_activity_segments` maybe they just changed the string now?

Comment: @cSn it wasn't changed intentionally. I've raised a bug to get that fixed.

Comment: Awesome @AndyTurner! Thanks! Do you think we could be getting like a better error message and/or error code for these cases in the future? I end up "guessing" that this particular error/msg was associated to an account that had no linked device for retrieving fitness info. (after replicating of course the scenario on my own) Thanks again!

Comment: @cSn FYI: the error messages should now be back again.